# Kotlin : Variable 'result' must be initialized

Tags: kotlin

The compiler is showing error Kotlin: Variable result must be initialized.

Here is the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kiAw.png)

Comment: Please provide your code here (instead of image)

Comment: You should provide a value for it in the `else` clause or return in it

Answer (score 1):

In the **when** statement there is missing an initialization of the **result** variable, because it's expected to be.

```
when(intent...) {
    "+" -> result = something...
    ...
   else {
       result = something else...
   }
}
```

Comment: And since `when` is an expression this can also be written as `val result = when(...) { "+" -> foo ... else -> bar }`

Comment: @Michael yes, you're right. I just wanted to point the problem, but not changing the author's solution.